# append same element into two places

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have the following html....

```
<div id="test">
    <div>
      <img /><img /><img />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img /><img /><img />
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#clickto').click(function(){
   $('<h1>hi</h1>').appendTo('#test div:nth-child(1)');
   $('<h1>hi</h1>').appendTo('#test div:nth-child(2)');
});
```

The same element I have to append since I appended two times. I think there is an easy way.

I tried this but appends to only one div:

```
$('<h1>hi</h1>').appendTo('#test div');
```

Answer (score 5):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/smZCy/)

This will do it

[:lt](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) documentation

`div:lt(2)` will select first two elements

```
$('<h1>hi</h1>').appendTo('#test div:lt(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it around

```
$('#test div').append($('<h1>hi</h1>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test">
<div class="select_me">
  <img /><img /><img />
</div>
<div class="select_me">
  <img /><img /><img />
</div>
</div>


 $('<h1>hi</h1>').appendTo('#test div.select_me');
```